# wsimport giving [WARNING] Current configuration of the parser doesn't allow a maxOccurs

Tags: java

while generating jar using wsimport command I am getting below warning,I was wondering if it is just a warning or the compiler does restrict my classes generated to 5000

parsing WSDL...

[WARNING] Current configuration of the parser doesn't allow a maxOccurs attribute value to be set greater than the value 5,000.

I am using JDK 1.7 I know if I change maxOccurs to outbound it will work but can anyone help me out to fix this one like adding some lines in xjb or additional parameter in wsimport tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
xjc -nv
```

option.

-nv do not perform strict validation of the input schema(s)

Comment: Hi Peter I was talking about the WSDL to JAVA Class ,XJC -nv works fine if I was using XSD to JAVA class.